# How to have 1 menu item click handled programatically while the others work from navigation graph in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

Basically I have a working drawer / menu, no issues. But now I want to add a new item to the menu which doesn't go anywhere, I just want to handle the click it in code.

I have the following menu in Android:

```
<group android:id="@+id/nav_menu_group_main"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_calendar_month"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_basic_information"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_perm_contact_calendar"
        android:title="@string/menu_basic_information" />
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/nav_menu_group_remove_ads">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_remove_ads"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_payments"
        android:title="@string/menu_remove_ads" />
</group>
```

I have the following navigation graph:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:name="com.systems.automaton.weeksgone.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_basic_information"
    android:name="com.systems.automaton.weeksgone.ui.basicinformation.BasicInformationFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_basic_information"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_basic_information" />
</fragment>
```

This is setup in MainActivity as follows:

```
val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = it.drawerLayout
val navView: NavigationView = it.navView
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)

appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
    R.id.nav_home), drawerLayout)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
    // this will never get called when nav_remove_ads is clicked
}
```

So the issue here is `addOnDestinationChangedListener` is never called for R.nav_remove_ads. So I can't do anything.

I can manually get the click if I do this:

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(object: NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // here it will get the click but now none of the other navigation stuff works anymore
    }
})
```

I can get the click however if I do this the navController is essentially useless, it won't process the other menu items and navigate to the fragments at all anymore.

So how can I have a menu item in a nav controller which doesn't go to a fragment or activity and can just be handled via code?

Comment: `addOnDestinationChangedListener` will never get called unless you add a fragment entry in the navGraph to the `menu_remove_ads` .. Do you intentionally remove it?

Comment: There's no fragment to navigate to. I just want to execute code when it's clicked, not navigate to anything (not even a fragment).